# How to check if an element h2 contain a text

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a button search, and it will show "No results found" or "another button for buy".

What I'm trying to do is to create an `if` to check if there is on page "No results found", click on the back button. If not, click on the buy button.

Here is HTML code:

```
<button> Search </button>
..
<div class="contents"> <h2>No results found<h/2> </div> #the message I want to check first
..
<button class="btn-standard> Buy Now </button> #buy button
...
<button class="back"> Back </button> #the button I want to click if no resul
```

And I have tried something like below:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[text()="No results found"]'):
   driver.find_element_by_class_name('back').click()
else:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Buy Now')]"))).click()
```

But it didn't work. Do I have to use `try / catch` codition?

ANOTHER EDIT:

I got this error now. I have no idea how to hide that element which obscure my Buy button.

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="btn-standard buyButton"> is not clickable at point (1086,641) because another element <div class="ut-click-shield showing interaction"> obscures it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with text as **No results found** would appear only after a unsuccessful search. So to lookout for the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='contents']//h2[text()='No results found']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='back' and contains(,. 'Back')]"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-standard' and contains(,. 'Buy Now')]"))).click()
```

Comment: and if the back button, contains no text, do I have to use the following code line?`    `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='back']"))).click()`
`

Comment: @PaulVio Yes, you are right, but you have to ensure the locator strategy `(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='back']")` identifies the desired element uniquely else you have refer the ancestor elements as we did in case of `//div[@class='contents']//h2`

Comment: Yea, works, but one more thing, and I hope it's done.. Can you have another look on my latest edit?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a method that checks if element exists

```
public boolean checkElementExists(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can put it inside if clause

```
if(!checkElementExists(By.xpath("//h2[text()="No results found"]")))
    click back
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_*` will throw an exception if the element doesn't exists, use `find_elements_*` and check if the returned list is not empty

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[text()="No results found"]')
if elements:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'back'))).click()
else:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Buy Now')]"))).click()
```

Comment: I get this error now: `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="back"> is not clickable at point (128,80) because another element <div class="click-shield showing interaction"> obscures it
`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of the element and check if the size of the element is greater than 0 or not and then you can click on it.
You can do it like:

```
 results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[text()="No results found"]')
 if(len(results)>0):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Back')]").click()
 else:
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Buy Now')]").click()
```